# Would a human survive being shot out of a trebuchet? (Not the landing)

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, physics

For reasons, groups of humans are bound together, placed in a barrels or such, which are then loaded onto trebuchets instead of their usual projectiles. Would these humans survive being launched?

Note that they do not need to survive its landing or hitting. They only need to be alive while the projectile is in the air.

Comment: this largely depends on the size and power of the trebuchet.

Comment: As pointed out, you haven't given much information. If they are thrown ten feet, the acceleration will be a lot less than if they are thrown 100ft or 1000ft.  The answer will be in the following link if you give the various measurements. https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/trebuchet-physics.html

Comment: Punkin Chunkin is a thing, and a fullsize orange pumpkin is not that much tougher than a seated and supported human. ( a 4 foot drop is usually easily survivable by both, a 15 foot drop is almost guaranteed damage)

Comment: @john Being able to launch a human puts a low end limit of the size. And as the acceleration forces in a trebuchet *decrease* as you scale it up, anything bigger than this low limit is easier. (similar linear acceleration, over longer time, and much larger radius reducing centripetal forces)

Comment: Skeet shooting with humans as targets?

Comment: @PcMan does the peak acceleration force go down or just the average acceleration force, the acceleration force on a trebuchets projectile changes drastically during the launch.

Comment: @john The main idea with a Trebuchet is that it applies *constant* force to the projectile, as nearly as it can. A trebuchet that has higher and lower transients in the pull is incorrectly designed. (It's part of the reason why a Trebuchet is so much better than a torsion catapult, which *does* have varying forces through its arc)

Answer (score 4):

The world's largest working trebuchet can [hurl a man-sized projectile at a speed of up to 70 m/s](https://www.thechalkface.net/resources/trebuchet_projectiles.pdf).

Working with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE54m0fojHQ&t=482s) of the trebuchet firing, it looks like it takes about 2 seconds to build up to that speed.

This puts the minimum acceleration on the projectile (AKA the person) at between 3 and 4 Gs.

I can't be bothered to do the math today, but I'm pretty sure that because it's centripetal acceleration from being pulled in a semi-circle that the projectile faces at least twice that acceleration when the arm is parallel to the ground.

Either way, that's well under the 10G that's considered fatal to people, and pretty close to being under the 5Gs required to keep a person conscious.

Particularly if it's designed with human cargo in mind, you could change the shape of the trebuchet slightly to make it accelerate slower or have a lower top speed, so I'd say it's fully realistic for at least some of these humans survive.

Comment: Also worth noting, this is a short-time acceleration -- two seconds or so -- vs. having to stand up to a minute or so of the high G (for instance, while pulling out of a dive in an airplane).  The shorter the exposure, the more G a person can take without death or serious injury.  A bigger question might be how the victims are packaged.  If they're lying flat on padding, they'll do much better than if they're tied to each other and standing.

Comment: obligatory XKCD: https://what-if.xkcd.com/116/

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers & comments have said, the acceleration depends on the construction of your trebuchet. Searching will find a number of sites that explain the physics of the trebuchet, for instance https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/trebuchet-physics.html  So you just need to do some math to determine the acceleration experienced by a projectile fired from a trebuchet of given dimensions & counterweight mass.

It has been demonstrated by experiment that humans can survive brief accelerations of at least 38 g: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stapp#Work_on_effects_of_deceleration  Just eyeballing pictures of typical trebuchets suggests that their accelerations are less than this, so the answer is probably yes.  You certainly could design one to be survivable.

Answer (score -3):

The space shuttle launched at an acceleration of something like [156 meters per second](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/466711main_AP_ST_ShuttleAscent.pdf) (reaches 8,000 meters per second in eight & a half minutes) & that didn't kill anyone.

[This trebuchet](https://www.thechalkface.net/resources/trebuchet_projectiles.pdf) can hurl objects at a top speed of 70 meters per second, it looks pretty standard for a trebuchet to me so I think we can safely go by that.

Having watched similar size trebuchet in action (TV, YouTube etc) I believe judging by eye that the counterweight takes no less than a second (probably more) to hit the floor (payload launch point).

Which would be an acceleration of 70 meters per second, even if I'm wildly out in my eyeballing and it's half a second that's still only an acceleration of 140 meters per second.

In short, the acceleration provided by the trebuchet is well within that of the space shuttle which is itself within human tolerance.

So, there is no plausible reason to suppose anyone would die as a result of being launched.

Unless they had a pre-existing condition.

Comment: I suggest you find a video and time it, rather than trying to eyeball it.